# Best way to "bundle" external dependencies in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

With AngularJS it is easy to split up the application and also include external modules that we want to use. But with the way we do it today the index.html can be littered with the different external references and it's hard to see which is really needed by the modules.

Is there a good way to handle how external dependencies of the modules (such as html templates, css and js files) are "included"?

Ideally we would like to just add one reference in index.html along with the reference to the external used angular module and this in turn includes the needed dependencies. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Angular [doesn't have a dependency loader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17411189/214446), you have two options:

1. Use a third-party loader like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) that fetches the files asynchronously one by one.
2. [Use a build-tool](http://dailyjs.com/2013/05/30/angularjs-6/) like browserify or Grunt to wrap everything into one javascript file that you can then include.