# Bootstrapping AngularJS javascript files through one javascript file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS, but with the little I have learn't and worked it, I aprreciate it has a fantastic client side framework, However I dont like it when I have to include all the files I need in my my index Page for instance

```
<script src="/js/lib/angular/ng-core/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/js/lib/angular/ng-module/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="/js/lib/angular/controller/main.js"></script>
<script src="/js/lib/angular/controller/home.js"></script>
<script src="/js/lib/angular/controller/insuranceType.js"></script>
<script src="/js/lib/angular/controller/insuranceCategory.js"></script>
<script src="/js/lib/angular/config/router.js"></script>
```

A user can just check source and download my project like this,

how can load only a javascript and in that I can bootstrap all my required angular javascript files? An idea is what I put below

**My Index.html Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  ...
    <script src="bootstrapmyfiles.js"></script>
  ...
</head>
</html>
<body>
</body>
```

**My bootstrapmyfiles.js File**

```
 //pseudocode here
 require("angular.js")
 //require other javascript files too
```

How can I achieve this please, Is there a way? seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949098/angularjs-include-the-javascript-files) but not satisfactory

Comment: You have two options .. see the answer for this similar SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25465923/best-way-to-bundle-external-dependencies-in-angularjs

Comment: What server technology do you use?

Comment: nodejs, but that is just used to startup

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 ways of bootstrapping angular files:

**Download files asynchronously from client when needed**. Angular itself doesn't provide such feature, but you can try to combine it with something like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). For example check [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-requirejs-angularjs-applications/). By the way Angular 2 is promised to be AMD ready.

**Prepare files on server**. Almost all web frameworks have some kind of bundling mechanism. So you can put all files in one and also minimize them.

> A user can just check source and download my project like this

You can't do nothing with that. Files are downloaded on client machine and that means he/she can view them. Putting all files in one bundle and minimizing (obfuscating) them, will make it less readable, but still it's possible to read source.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com) to compile (and minify/uglify, if you want it) all your javascript files into only one when releasing your application.